# Third party components in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Has anyone had experience with using third party components in Sharepoint please?
I am considering using Infragistics or Telerik. But would love to hear any case studies of how these or any others can integrate well with sharepoint. I am using Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at the SharePoint Kits from the most famous .NET components vendors:

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Core/sharepoint.xml)

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/sharepoint/overview.aspx)

[ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SharePointWebParts/)

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/sharepoint.aspx#Overview)

Answer (score 2):

There are some Frameworks or Controls which don't work well in SharePoint. In SharePoint you always have to care about multiple Servers in a farm. There are also some JavaScript Controls which are great, for example I couldn't get ExtJS working with SharePoint 2010.

In my opinion it's safer to use Silverlight and use the fancy UI controls inside of a Silverlight component. By doing it this way, we could ensure that we don't harm the SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is still an ASP.Net application and so I really don't think there will be any issues.

There are lot of clients I worked/working with who uses Telerik with SP2010

Comment: SharePoint is .NET 3.5. Make sure your components don't need 4.0